# Object detection only when a particular type of object is on the image

Tags: image-processing, object-recognition, deep-learning, object-detection

Apologies if this has been answered already.

I am very new to computer vision. I am kind of familiar with object detection and classification for many types of classes, which involves training data with all the different classes, then detecting the object and at the end classifying.

However, my current problem aims to recognize only one type of objects. Let's say that I want to make an algorithm which detects a cat when the cat is on the image. So essentially, I am only interested for the bounding box, only when a cat is present. What would be the process for something like this? Thank you very much all!

Comment: but to know there's a cat in the image, you would need to detect the cat... which is the harder problem than detecting where it is if you know it's in the image.

Comment: Yeah, so do i train images with cats and images without cats making it a binary classification problem then?

Comment: If you want to train something, you can train a "cat probability and position" detector. As long as the estimated cat probability is low, you ignore the position, else you claim there's a cat and use the position. But the problem is that cats as a general problem probably aren't the easiest to reliably detect and put a bounding box around. How much training data do you have access to?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I haven't go a training set yet, I am trying to conceptualise the problem.

Comment: Then you'd probably use a pretrained cat-classifying network based in e.g. imageNet

Comment: Better fit for [DS.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com).